# restrict keyword with multiple read-only literal string

Tags: c, restrict

Can the `restrict` keyword be used like below

- Interface:

  ```
  int func(const char * restrict str1, const char * restrict str2);
  ```
- Calling:

  ```
  func("something", "something");
  ```

There is possibility that the compiler makes the same pointer for the string literal `"something"` to optimize footprint. In such cases, `str1` and `str2` will point same area.

Is that legal?

Well, in my guess, it is okay, because for example in this definition:

```
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

Can it be used like:

```
printf("%s something", "something");
```

In this case, `"something"` can be stored at the same place in memory to optimize footprint.

However, I have to make sure it is safe and legal because I want to keep my source code portably and legally.

If someone know some definition, please teach me.

---

Addition (20180804 16:07 JST):

I want to comply with the standard.
if the standard says that restrict pointer must not point same addres,

Case calling the function like:

```
    func("something", "something"); can be illegal.
```

because it is possible compiler use same pointer for "something".

And illegal means this code behavior is undefined, anything could happen.

So, in easy way, I can avoid to use "restrict".

But I want to use it to make quick programs.
And it will be expected this:

```
    read-only member with keyword "restrict" can be stored in duplicative area.
```

Because, I saw interface for printf().
If const string can not point same addres, printf will be unuseful.

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known reason that `restrict` isn't very useful. IIRC it came up with `fopen`.

Comment: Thanks to your post.
I understand you mean.
fopen interface:
FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode);
if use fopen("filename.rar", "r"); it could be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

`int func(const char * restrict str1, const char * restrict str2);` is a curious example.

Without quoting the C spec, which in the case of `restrict` is none to easy to decipher, `restrict` means that the data pointed to will only change due to what `func()` or its called sub-functions do via *that* pointer.

---

> In such cases, str1 and str2 will point same area

Is that legal?

Consider `str1` and `str2` point to the same place and the `func(g_temp, g_temp);` call is *not* legal.

```
char g_temp[100] = "Hello world";

int func(const char * restrict str1, const char * restrict str2) {
  g_temp[0]++;
  puts(str1);
}

void foo() {
  func(g_temp, g_temp);
}
```

---

In the case of `func("something", "something");`, it is OK as the data pointed by `str1, str2`, though they may overlap, do not change due to `func()`.

It is not overlapping that is the issue, it is can `func1()` rely on the data pointed to by `restrict str1` only changes due to access with `str1`.  Since `str1` points to `const` data, `func1()` is not going to directly change it and neither will `g_temp[0]++;` since `"something"` does not involve `g_temp[]`.

Comment: It will also be defined behavior because neither `str1` or `str2` are modified within `func`, see [C11 Standard - 6.7.3.1 Formal definition of restrict(p10)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1p10). (at least that definition is better than the strict aliasing rule...but still has its gray areas)

Comment: Thanks to your post.
I agree with you.
In some case, it will work without any problem.
I added article to my question to express better what I want.